# how to run php file with parameter using notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++, nppexec

How to run php file with parameter using **notepad++**

**test.php**

```
<?php 
    /* ------- 
        test.php
    ------- */
    if(!isset($_GET['file'])){
        exit;
    }
    $code=file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
    echo $code;

?>
```

---

> demo_file.php -----$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)

contents:

**hello world**

---

```
cd "D:\PHPnow-1.5.6\htdocs\zc_default\my_debug_fw"<br>
"d:\PHPnow-1.5.6\php-5.2.14-Win32\php.exe" "test.php" [what here?]
```

how to send **"demo_file.php"** as `$_GET['file']` to **test.php** ?

The console finally should output:`...... hello world`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When utilizing PHP from the command line the arguments aren't passed in as part of the $_GET superglobal.  They're passed in as part of the $_SERVER - superglobal where $_SERVER['argc'] is the number of arguments and $_SERVER['argv'] is an array of the argument values.  $_SERVER['argv'][0] is the name of the php script and $_SERVER['argv'][1] would be the first argument.

```
    if($_SERVER['argc'] < 2){
        exit("Usage: php test.php <file>");
    }

    $code = file_get_contents($_SERVER['argv'][1]);
```

Per your example above...

Answer (score 0):

After closing Notepad++, go to `%APPDATA%/Notepad++` and open `shortcuts.xml` file in Notepad. Within        append the following line.

`<Command name="Launch Server" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="90">chrome &quot;http://localhost/index.php?file=$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>`

Now change the content of default index.php in htdocs to

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    {   $uri = 'https://'; }

    else
    {   $uri = 'http://'; }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if(isset($_GET['file']))
    {
        $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $_GET['file']);
        $file = str_replace($root, '', $file);

        header("Location: http://localhost{$file}");
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');
        //header('Location: '.$uri.'/yourproject/');
    }
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

Now run Xampp and click `Notepad++>Run>Launch Server` or use Shortcut Key `CTRL+ALT+Z` to directly run the code!